# How private method of super class are resolved?

Tags: java

```
class A{ 
  private void sayA(){
     System.out.println("Private method of A");
  }
  public static void main(String args[]){
      A instanceA=new B();
      instanceA.sayA();
  }
}

class B extends A{
}
```

I was expecting it to throw a run time exception as at compile-time the compiler checks if `sayA()` can be called on a reference of `A` and at run-time it'll check if `sayA()` can be called on `B`'s object. But it instead printed "*Private method of A*".

Comment: Move the `main` under class `B` and you should get the compile error.

Comment: Why is this question getting voted up? I don't think the question provokes any insightful thought.

Comment: Don't we have a generic "How I don't understand the vizibility?" question already to flag as duplicate? If not, it's probably a good question :)

Comment: It's voted up bcoz it's a very good question, and thought provoking one

Answer (score 15):

Accessibility is a compile time concept (reflected in Reflection APIs).

[From the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6)

> Note that accessibility is a static property that can be determined at
>   compile time; it depends only on types and declaration modifiers.

That is, the compiler doesn't care what the runtime type of the instance referenced by your variable named `instanceA` will be

```
A instanceA = new B();
```

It only cares that you invoked a method on a reference of static type `A`. That method is `private` and since you are within the body of the class which declares it, it is visible, and therefore usable.

> Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared private, and access
>   is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level
>   class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or
>   constructor.

---

For spiderman in comments, consider the following

```
class A {
    private void privateMethod () {
        System.out.println("private method");
    }
    public void publicMethod() {
        privateMethod();
    }
}

class B extends A {}

class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B().publicMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is too good, but I can relate it only to why there is no compilation error in this scenario. But to the question of why there is no runtime error, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @spiderman Accessibility is not a property of the runtime. It is a property of the compile time. The rules from the JLS are applied at compile time. They are meant to catch everything (with a valid compiler). There would be no possibility of these rules being broken at runtime (except in the case of reflection where that is handled differently).

Comment: Ok, thank you +1 . I am forced to make myself agree that it is 'how it works' as per the rules. However, in this example by the OP, doesn't it showcase that the rues are being broken at runtime? and it's not able to catch it because the accessibility is only a compile-time property? .. Please lemme know if you're getting my question. Appreciate your time

Comment: @spiderman I understand your question. You're not breaking encapsulation in the OP's sample. You're accessing code that's `private` to `A` within `A`. Why shouldn't that be allowed?

Comment: Accessing a code that's `private` to `A` within `A` should be fine. Accessing a code that's `private` to `A` but outside of  `A` should only be a problem. But,  What is difficult for me to understand is that , `instanceA` is referring to object of `B` and at runtime `instanceA.sayA()` will attempt to call the `sayA()` method of `B`, and this method is not visible/present in `B`. I think I am missing some concepts :(

Comment: @spiderman Consider the exampled I've edited into my answer. The `private` method ends up being called correctly. At runtime, we have a `B` object, but somehow the `privateMethod` gets invoked. What you have to understand is encapsulation and what it is we chose to expose as an interface (not the `interface` type, but an API that other classes can use).

Comment: Got it, thru that example.. Appreciate your efforts to help me out, unfortunately I can do only a single upvote.   This comment from @1337joe was also meaningful in getting your point - '`B` extends `A`, so any instance of `B` is also an instance of `A`. Therefore the private method declared by `A` exists in `instanceA` but only class `A` has visibility to it.'

Comment: I understand how much precious your time is, you resolve multiple SO posts within a minute, and I am so happy that you took your precious time in making me understand in return of no upvotes or bounty! .. just being Human! Have a good day

Answer (score 12):

`private` means that only the class that declares the field can see it.  Because you're calling `instanceA.sayA();` from within class `A` the method is visible and the code both compiles and runs.  If you were to try to call that method from within class `B` or any other class you would get the compile warning that `The method sayA() from the type A is not visible`

Comment: At runtime, `instanceA` is referring to object of `B`, then how does `instanceA.sayA();` gets resolved?  Compile-time I agree and understand as it is as what you explained

Comment: `B extends A`, so any instance of `B` is *also* an instance of `A`.  Therefore the private method declared by `A` exists in `instanceA` but only class `A` has visibility to it.

Comment: perfect.. got it .. I stopped pulling my hair.

Answer (score 5):

It's because you're assigning B to A, so the resulting instance has access to the methods of A.

If you change to `B instanceA=new B()`, the subsequent line will not compile (which I believe is what you expected?).

```
class A{ 
  private void sayA(){
     System.out.println("Private method of A");
  }
  public static void main(String args[]){
      B instanceA=new B();
      instanceA.sayA(); # This line won't compile/run.
  }
}

class B extends A{
}
```

Comment: Is this actually true in Java? It seems pretty inconsistent. C# does allow this, regardless of the type of the variable (as long as it derives from `A`, of course) - but you can't touch `B`'s privates from `A`, anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

InstanceA is the instance of A actually, so it can call the functions of A, but if the function is private, means that only the class declares the field can see it.
eg:

```
public class A
{
    private void sayA(){
        System.out.println("Private method of A");
     }

    public  void funOfA(){
        System.out.println("fun of A");
     }
     public static void main(String args[]){
         A instanceA=new B();
         instanceA.sayA();
         instanceA.funOfA();
     }

}



public class B extends A
{
    public void funOfB()
    {
        System.out.println("fun of B");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        A instanceA=new B();
        instanceA.funOfA();
     //  instanceA.sayA(); // This Line won't compile and run.
     //   instanceA.funOfB(); // This Line won't compile and run.
        B instanceB = new B();
        instanceB.funOfA();
        instanceB.funOfB();
     //   instanceB.sayA(); // This Line won't compile and run.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only virtual methods are really parts of the class *instance* - you can imagine all the other methods as simply being a static method that take an argument called `this`.

So when you rewrite the code to show this more explicitly (note that I'm using C#, Java is a bit different but the same principle *mostly* applies):

```
class A
{
  private static void sayA(A @this)
  {
    "Hi from A".Dump();
  }

  public static void Test()
  {
    sayA(new B());
  }
}

class B : A { }
```

This makes it much more obvious what the scope of the method is - it doesn't *really* tie in to the *instance* of the type, only to the type itself. So no matter whether you call `new B().sayA()` or `new A().sayA()`, the same method is called, just with a different argument.

On the other hand, if you're writing code from inside of `B`, the `sayA` method simply isn't accessible - again, `A.sayA(...)` is obviously inaccessible, since it's private to `A`.

This changes when you make the method public or protected, and virtual (default in Java). In that case, the actual method that's called depends on the runtime type you're calling the method on, not the compile-time type, nor the scope you call it from. This means that `new B().VirtualA()` will call the same method as `((A)new B()).VirtualA()`, even though the compile-time types are different. And of course `new A().VirtualA()` may (or may not - depending on whether `B` overrides `VirtualA`) be a different method.